# Why No ops registered when I try to load frozen model in Android NDK?

Tags: tensorflow, android-ndk

I want to use c++ tensorflow API through ndk and cmake, I can create the library but when I load a frozen model a lot of errors like this when I try to load graph:

> E/native: op_kernel.cc:1148 OpKernel ('op: "PopulationCount"
>   device_type: "CPU" constraint { name: "T" allowed_values { list {
>   type: DT_INT32 } } }') for unknown op: PopulationCount

So I understand that my library does not support the operations. 
Do I need to add another library to support these operations?

I based my Cmake script on this [Cmakelist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/android) and
I used the [build_android_all.sh](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_android.sh) script to build the dependencies for armeabi-v7a.

This is how my cmake script looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
include(ExternalProject)
SET(PROJECT_NAME tf_native_lib)
SET(OpenCV_FOUND true )
SET(PREBUILT_DIR ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT_DIR}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen)
SET(TARGET_NSYNC_LIB ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT_DIR}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile    /downloads/nsync/builds/${ANDROID_ABI}.android.c++11)
FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             ${PROJECT_NAME}
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.h
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/TensorflowInferenceHandler.h
             src/main/cpp/TensorflowInferenceHandler.cpp
             )

add_library(lib_proto STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_proto PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${PREBUILT_DIR}/protobuf_android/${ANDROID_ABI}/lib/libprotobuf.a)

add_library(lib_nsync STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_nsync PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
   ${TARGET_NSYNC_LIB}/libnsync.a)

add_library(lib_tf STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_tf PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
${PREBUILT_DIR}/lib/android_${ANDROID_ABI}/libtensorflow-core.a)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DIS_SLIM_BUILD \
                      -std=c++11 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions \
                      -O2 -Wno-narrowing -fomit-frame-pointer \
                      -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -fPIE -fPIC \
                      -ftemplate-depth=900 \
                      -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI \
                      -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_STATIC_INITIALIZER")

 set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} \
                               -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition \
                               -Wl,--whole-archive \
                               -fPIE -pie -v")



# MESSAGE("tensorflow lib dir ${TENSORFLOW_LIB_DIR}")

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       ${PROJECT_NAME}
                       ${OpenCV_LIBS}
                       android
                       dl
                       log
                       m
                       z
                       jnigraphics
                       lib_tf
                       lib_proto
                       lib_nsync)

include_directories(
                   ${OPENCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                   ${PREBUILT_DIR}/proto
                   ${PREBUILT_DIR}/protobuf_android/${ANDROID_ABI}/include
                   ${PREBUILT_DIR}/nsync/public
                   ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT_DIR}/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/downloads/eigen
                   ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT_DIR}/bazel-tensorflow/external/nsync/public
                   ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT_DIR}/bazel-genfiles
                   ${TENSORFLOW_ROOT_DIR}
                   ../../../cpp_utils)
```

If this is not possible, where are the sources to link the tensorflow_inference.so with my Jni Sources?

Thanks in advance.

Unai.

Comment: were you able to figure this out? If you did could you please let me know? Thanks.

Comment: Solved it. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PopulationCount` and few other Ops are declared in `tensorflow/core/ops/bitwise_ops.cc`. Add that file to the end of `/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/tf_op_files.txt`. Then recompile the `Tensorflow`. That is what worked for me.